# Visual Studio: development tools defects list

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a public resource to view, submit, track defects reported for the different products within Visual Studio?

Suppose you observe some behavior in Visual Studio that you suspect might be a defect, and you'd like to determine whether:

- it's been submitted to the VS team
- it's been fixed in an upcoming release
- the behavior is by design
- others are seeing the same behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio ?